# Can't get counter to work

Tags: java, output, counter, java.util.scanner, java-io

I'm really new at this so forgive my ignorance..
So this is what I need to do:

1. Determine how many bottle caps each person has to open in order to find a winning cap. The answer is 1 in 5.
2. Prompt the user for the number of trials.
3. Read back the data for all of the trials from the output file.
4. Calculate the average number of caps opened in order to win a prize.
5. Print the result to the screen.

This is what I've tried, but the counter isn't working.. Help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;

public class BottleCapPrize
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
    {

        int trials = 0;
        int loop = 1;
        int winCounter = 0;
        int random;
        double average;

        //
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter (new File("MonteCarloMethod.txt"));

        //
        System.out.print("Number of trials: ");
        trials = in.nextInt();

        //
        for(loop = 1; loop <= trials; loop++)
        {
            random = rand.nextInt(5);
            if(random == 1)
            {
                outFile.println("Trial: " + loop + " WIN!");
                winCounter++;
            }
            outFile.println("Trial: " + loop + " LOSE");
        }

        //
        average = winCounter / trials;
        outFile.println("Average number of caps to win: " + average);
        System.out.println("Average number of caps to win: " + average);

        outFile.close();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Define "isn't working" - what exactly isn't working?

Comment: I thought the counter wasn't working, as in I thought it remained at 0 all the time, turns out that wasn't the problem afterall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem you may be facing is dividing two `int` and expecting a `double` result

```
int trials = 0;
int winCounter = 0;
double average;

average = winCounter / trials;
```

What's going to happen divding two `int` is that you will lose precision. instead make the `int` into `double`. Or *at least* one of them.

```
double trials = 0;
double winCounter = 0;
double average;

average = winCounter / trials;
```

And use `in.nextDouble()`

Comment: thanks for the help! It seems i've been looking at all the wrong places when the answer was so simple..

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your loop/counter is working. What the problem is is that average calculation isn't correct. You need to make sure the division numbers are treated as floats. So either do the below calculation, making sure winCounter and trials are both treated as floats:

```
average = (float) winCounter / (float) trials;
```

Or declare winCounter and trials as floats.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. I guess I was just looking at the wrong places. Got it fixed and everything is working now

Comment: No problem. As peeskillet says, please accept one of the two answers you went with and that worked for you.